# Is there any way to export publication contents from the DSpace assetstore?

Tags: dspace

Is there any way to export publication contents from the DSpace assetstore using either DSpace command or third party tools?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The following documentation will describe a couple options for exporting items.

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Importing+and+Exporting+Items+via+Simple+Archive+Format#ImportingandExportingItemsviaSimpleArchiveFormat-ExportingItems

and

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Importing+and+Exporting+Content+via+Packages#ImportingandExportingContentviaPackages-Disseminating